# JavaFx Platform.runLater Application Not Responsive

Tags: java, javafx, webview

In the following simplified JavaFx program it keeps saying Application Not Responsive. When I comment out the Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {...} it doesn't crash. Any ideas what is wrong and how I can fix it?

```
package apptest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class apptest {


    public static JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();          


    public static void main(String[] args){

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 


        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override 
        public void run() { 

        JPanel login = new JPanel();
        login.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        login.setBounds(0, 0, 415, 180);     


        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
        engine.load("http://www.google.com");

        VBox root = new VBox(webView);
        root.setStyle( "-fx-focus-color: transparent;");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,414,179);    

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        scrollPane.setContent(webView);                              

        root.getChildren().addAll(scrollPane);
        jfxPanel.setScene(scene); 
        frame.add(login, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        login.add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        }

      }); 


        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(415,180);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice defaultScreen = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        Rectangle rect = defaultScreen.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
        int x = 10;
        int y = (int) rect.getMaxY() - (frame.getHeight() + 50);        
        frame.setLocation(x, y);
        frame.setVisible(true); 


    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the answer, I want to ask if you really need to embed JavaFX in a Swing application. These are two different toolkits and using both together makes things quite difficult, particularly because you have to manage two different threads of execution (the AWT event dispatch thread, on which all Swing work must take place, and the FX Application Thread, on which all JavaFX work must take place).

Assuming you really do need to embed JavaFX in a Swing frame instead of a JavaFX Stage, you need to create the Swing components on the AWT event dispatch thread, using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`. The JavaFX controls need to be created on the FX Application thread, using `Platform.runLater()`. In your code you create and configure the `JFrame` on the main thread (not the AWT thread) and create the `JPanel` on the FX Application Thread (again, not the AWT thread). This, I believe, causes the application to deadlock.

The basic outline for how to thread this correctly is shown in the [Javadocs for `JFXPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html).

One other note is that your layout structure is wrong. You add the `webView` directly to a `VBox`:

```
VBox root = new VBox(webView);
```

but then you place the same `webView` in a `ScrollPane`:

```
scrollPane.setContent(webView);
```

This adds the same component to the scene graph twice, which is not allowed (and makes no sense anyway). Since `WebView` implements its own scrolling, you can simply omit the `ScrollPane` entirely.

Your application code, again assuming you need to mix Swing and JavaFX, should look like

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

public class apptest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create swing components on AWT thread:

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()  -> {
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JPanel login = new JPanel();
            login.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            login.setBounds(0, 0, 415, 180);
            JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
            frame.add(login, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            login.add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            // Create JavaFX content on FX Application Thread:

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {


                    WebView webView = new WebView();
                    WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
                    engine.load("http://www.google.com");

                    VBox root = new VBox(webView);
                    root.setStyle("-fx-focus-color: transparent;");
                    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 414, 179);

                    jfxPanel.setScene(scene);

                }

            });

            frame.setLayout(null);
            frame.setSize(415, 180);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            GraphicsDevice defaultScreen = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
            Rectangle rect = defaultScreen.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
            int x = 10;
            int y = (int) rect.getMaxY() - (frame.getHeight() + 50);
            frame.setLocation(x, y);
            frame.setVisible(true);


        });

    }


}
```